Instagram basic APi deprecated
I was integrating the Instagram Basic API so users could connect their Instagram account to my application (0Auth). However, from what I've read, Facebook is going to deprecate this API. I wanted to know if there’s any replacement or something similar so that my users can connect their Instagram account to my service. I just need to collect the Instagram username; I don’t need posts or anything else. Thank you very much.
enter image description here
I checked if the Graph API can do that, but I think that only works for professional or business accounts. I need it for any account type.

I just saw the message: "On September 4, 2024, we announced the deprecation of the Instagram Basic Display API.
Starting December 4, 2024, all requests to the Instagram Basic Display API will return an error message. We recommend that you migrate your app to the Instagram API to avoid any disruption to your services.
Visit our News for Developers blog post to learn more."
Here is the link for the Instagram API with Facebook Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-facebook-login/
Here is the link for the Instagram API with Instagram Login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-instagram-login

Yeah, I checked that but only works for creators and busness accounts.
